# Calling method after Optional.filter() without passing in object

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I can understand the below:

```
user
  .filter(u -> "Sam".equals(u.getName()))
  .ifPresent(this::doSomethingWithUser);
```

if `user.getName` is equal to `"Sam"` then pass `user` to local method `doSomethingWithUser()`.

However, what if I simply wanted to call a local method, without passing `user` but keeping the check that `user.getName` is equal to `"Sam"`?

Does this use case make using `Optional` redundant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just ignore the mandatory function parameter. This means you cannot use shorthand `::` syntax and goes like this:

```java
user
  .filter(u -> "Sam".equals(u.getName()))
  .ifPresent(u -> doSomethingWithoutUser());
```

Comment: Interesting question... I've posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58734350/is-adapting-a-no-arg-method-into-a-consumer-bad-form

Comment: Sure, to fix the incorrect comment. I meant converting a *`Consumer` into a `Runnable`*. Not sure how effective or good of a practice is it!!

Answer (score 1):

You can just check for the presence of the `Optional` for such case:

```
if(user.filter(u -> "Sam".equals(u.getName()).isPresent()) {
    // call your method without user
}
```